Can you center a plot using R patchwork
This is about organizing plots in R markdown document. Say we create three plots:
library(patchwork)
library(tidyverse)

a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot A")
b <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot B")
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot C")

My organization is:
Plot<- a+b+c +plot_layout(ncol = 2)

It’s OK. But what I really want is:
plot<- a /(b + c) + 
  plot_layout(ncol = 2)

Except that all three plots are the same size, the upper centered.
Something very similar can be done with plot_spacer():
plot<- plot_spacer() + a + plot_spacer() /(b + plot_spacer() + c) 

But that decrease the size of the plots. Is there a way to keep the size of the plots, only center the upper one?

design <- "
  #11#
  2233"

wrap_elements(full =  a) + b + c + plot_layout(design = design, widths = 1)

The wrap_elements part is used to make the plots equal in width. (Though I haven't been able to get them to be the same height without manually adding heights = c(1.2,1))
As the patchwork author notes here, "the issue is that the y-axis of the top plot influences the width of plots spanning it's location. The easiest way is to remove alignment from the top plot by putting it inside wrap_elements()."


The method provided by jon-spring should work if you don't want to strictly center justification. With the latest patchwork (version 1.3.0 https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/386, you can now install it from the github), we can just remove the spaces of the y-axis when alignment (panel'll still be aligned, this ensure the top plot is in the center).
knitr::opts_knit$set(upload.fun = identity)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Plot A")
b <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Plot B")
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Plot C")

free(a, "space", "l") + b + c +
  plot_layout(design = "#11#
                        2233")


Created on 2024-09-14 with reprex v2.1.0
~
To better see the difference, let's use the example from https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/319.
If centered, the top plot panel should align the x-axis of bottom plot in value 6.
design <- "###AAAA###
           ###AAAA###
           BBCCDDEEFF
           JJKKLLMMNN"
f <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))
wrap_plots(wrap_elements(full = f),
  f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f,
  design = design
)


wrap_plots(free(f, "space", "l"),
  f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f,
  design = design
)



Thanks, Yun. Good point, centering is not great, but I'm missing something: "free" is recognized, but I get: Error in free(f, "space", "l") : unused arguments ("space", "l"), both in the "my" example (a,b and c) and the one you quote (f). What am I missing?

Sorry for the missing version of the patchwork, this is a un-released patchwork. See https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/386. You can install it from the github now or wait for the version 1.3.0.
